# How to cast a value pulled out of dense rank function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

In the below query, I want to cast Dense Rank function as nvarchar(255) but it is giving syntax error. I have following questions -

1. Is it possible to cast a value returned out of dense rank function?
2. If yes, what is the syntax?

---

```
 SELECT cast('P' AS NVARCHAR(3))                                                                                                                                                                                                            AS ADDRESS_TYPE_CD,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMER KEY] 
                             ORDER BY [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 1], 
                                      [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 2], 
                                      [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 3] + [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 4], 
                                      [PRIMARY CITY], 
                                      [PRIMARY STATE], 
                                      [PRIMARY ZIP], 
                                      [PRIMARY COUNTRY] ) AS ADDRESS_FLAG,
       [CUSTOMER KEY],
       [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                            AS PA1,
       CASE
         WHEN [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 1] = [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 2] THEN NULL
         ELSE [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 2]
       END                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 AS PA2,
       [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 3] + [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 4]                                                                                                                                                                                 AS PA3,
       [PRIMARY CITY]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      AS PCity,
       [PRIMARY STATE]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     AS PS,
       [PRIMARY ZIP]                                                                                                                                                                                                                       AS PZ,
       [PRIMARY COUNTRY]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   AS PC
FROM   mtb.DBO.EnrichedFile
WHERE  APPLICATION <> 'RBC'
```

Comment: Did you even trying to google? There are many documents regarding the Rank function.

Comment: I know what rank and dense rank is @Maverick. However, my question is how to cast a column created out of dense rank function.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL and Oracle, if the question is about SQL Server? Also, where do you actually cast that column, and where is the error?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Because I have to cast it in Oracle, SQLserver and MySQL db. However, I need to know if it is possible or not. If yes, then I need the syntax only for any one of them. Currently, it is throwing syntax error and I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi - MySQL doesn't even support `DENSE_RANK`. The square brackets are invalid in Oracle. Did you tag incorrectly just to get more views?

Comment: I tried this -

cast((DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMER KEY] ORDER BY [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 1],[MAILING ADDRESS LINE 2],[MAILING ADDRESS LINE 3]+[MAILING ADDRESS LINE 4],[MAILING CITY],[MAILING STATE],[MAILING ZIP],[MAILING COUNTRY]) as nvarchar(255)) AS ADDRESS_FLAG

Comment: @MartinSmith I am sorry I was not sure about dense rank not used in MySQL. I corrected the tags.

Comment: Well this works fine. `SELECT CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY number) AS NVARCHAR(255)) FROM master..spt_values` I presume the brackets are messed up somewhere in your query.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I do see a number of commas missing, probably that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 CAST((DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMER KEY] 
                            ORDER BY [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 1],
                                     [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 2],
                                     [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 3]+[MAILING ADDRESS LINE 4],
                                     [MAILING CITY],
                                     [MAILING STATE],
                                     [MAILING ZIP],
                                     [MAILING COUNTRY]) as nvarchar(255)) AS ADDRESS_FLAG
```

Should be

```
SELECT 
 CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMER KEY] 
                            ORDER BY [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 1],
                                     [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 2],
                                     [MAILING ADDRESS LINE 3]+[MAILING ADDRESS LINE 4],
                                     [MAILING CITY],
                                     [MAILING STATE],
                                     [MAILING ZIP],
                                     [MAILING COUNTRY]) as nvarchar(255)) AS ADDRESS_FLAG
```

You have a surplus opening bracket.

Why are you casting this to `nvarchar(255)` anyway though?

Even if there is some legitimate reason for wanting it as a string the maximum value it can possibly have is `9223372036854775807` so `varchar(19)` would be sufficient.

Comment: I am using nvarchar(255) to load it in a target table which has same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT CAST(ADDRESS_FLAG AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS ADDRESS_FLAG_STR,
       --... blah blah blah
FROM
(
 SELECT --.. blah blah blah
        DENSE_RANK() ... blah blah ...  AS ADDRESS_FLAG,
        --... blah blah blah
) SUB
```

I've found with the OVER function you need to put them in a sub query before you can manipulate them.  There are just a few things you can do with as if they were a normal field -- you can always refactor once you get the query working.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I made it work without using a subquery. I am posting my answer now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
cast(DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMER KEY] ORDER BY [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 1],[PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 2],[PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 3] + [PRIMARY ADDRESS LINE 4],[PRIMARY CITY],[PRIMARY STATE],[PRIMARY ZIP],[PRIMARY COUNTRY] ) as nvarchar(255)) AS ADDRESS_FLAG
```